# Drawing-Sword issues with animation

Tags: animation

What happens is that I have a sword that sits on the hip of a player-controlled knight character. I created a "draw sword" animation where the knight reaches and draws his sword. I have bone constraints so that when the frames align so that the knight's hand reaches the sword, the sword constraints to the knights hand. When playing the animation, out-of-game, everything works fine.

When I hit "P" to play the game I make my character draw his sword, but the sword doesn't move or change its constraint. Things to note are that the sword is an appended object from another file.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue and can help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I read that, in the game engine, *Child of* is partially supported- you can parent to objects but not to bones.

Add an empty to the character's hand bone and also have another at the hip where the sword rests when sheathed, parented to the hip bone.

Then you could try parenting the sword armature (using child of constraint) to the empty. You could also try with the sword object itself, without the sword's armature.

Comment: Two questions: When you say parent an empty to the hand, do you mean the body? My entire knight body is on object with no separations. Secondly, when you say "parent the sword to that" do you mean the sword object or the sword armature?

Comment: edited the answer for clarity